# "Required package rtl not found" when building with Hudson

Tags: delphi, continuous-integration, hudson, delphi-xe

I am trying to get [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) to work with my Delphi project. I am using the following batch file to build my project (as suggested in this [blog post](http://christerblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/25/using-hudson-to-build-delphi-projects/)):

```
call "C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\8.0\bin\rsvars.bat"
msbuild /p:Win32LibraryPath="$(BDS)\lib;$(BDS)\lib\win32\release;$(BDS)\lib\win32\debug;$(BDSUSERDIR)\Imports;$(BDS)\Imports;$(BDSCOMMONDIR)\Dcp;$(BDS)\include;" /t:build /p:config=Debug /verbosity:detailed "MyProject\src\MyProject.dproj"
if errorlevel 1 exit 1
```

I always end up with the error

```
Embarcadero Delphi for Win32 compiler version 22.0
Copyright (c) 1983,2010 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
Fatal: E2202 Required package 'rtl' not found
```

I don't understand this as `rtl.dcp` is in "$(BDS)\lib\win32\release" which is on the library path. I am using runtime packages by the way.

Any hints what I can do to solve this?

**Edit** It seems that the paths do not end up in the command line, which looks something like (after removing project-specific paths):

```
C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\8.0\bin\dcc32.exe -$O- -$W+ --inline:off -$A4 -$R+ -$Q+ --doc --no-config -B -LUrtl;vcl;ReportingR;ComponentsR -Q -AWinTypes=Windows;WinProcs=Windows;DbiTypes=BDE;DbiProcs=BDE;DbiErrs=BDE -DDEBUG;CONSTRAINT_CHECKING;_VER6;EUREKALOG_VER6;EurekaLog -V -VN -GD --drc -W-SYMBOL_DEPRECATED -W-SYMBOL_PLATFORM -W-UNIT_PLATFORM -W-UNIT_DEPRECATED   Myproject.dpr
```

Comment: try sysinternals process monitor to get what paths and where are tried. if those variables are expanded or not and to which values.

Comment: @Arioch'The any more specific hints on how I do that? Which process should I watch? And what exactly to watch for?

Comment: Why do you need to set `Win32LibraryPath`? Doesn't rsvars.bat do that?

Comment: @David: rsvars.bat set $BSD, $BSDCOMMONDIR, $PATH and some .NET framework stuff

Comment: All the processes that are engaged into building process.
And compare command lines and config files when you call them from IDE and from your bat

Comment: okay, command lines differ (see my edit): how can I get hudson and msbuild to include additional command line parameters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer in a comment to the original blog post. It turns out that in Delphi XE they changed the name of the `Win32LibraryPath` property to `DelphiWin32LibraryPath`. Changing the batch script accordingly fixes the issue.

Comment: For me, it was ensuring that on the `Continua CI` build server, `MSBuild` had the `DelphiLibraryPath` property to get Delphi XE to build. XE2 and up worked fine. I'll write up a blog post after I got some other things to work.

Comment: Delphi 2007, 2010: `Win32LibraryPath`, Delphi XE and up: `DelphiLibraryPath`. Delphi 2007: `Win32LibraryPath=%BDSRoot%\Lib\%Configuration%;%BDSRoot%\Lib`; Delphi 2010: `Win32LibraryPath=%BDSRoot%\Lib\%Configuration%;%BDSRoot%\Lib`, Delphi XE+: `DelphiLibraryPath=%BDSRoot%\Lib\%Platform%\%Configuration%`

Answer (score 1):

The first path $(BDS)\Lib for XE,XE2 and XE 10.2 should be change for $(BDSLIB)\$(PLATFORM)\release